# Headless Blender using Cycles without X-server?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, command-line

I would like to render with Cycles on a headless machine, without an X-server.

Has anyone done this with success?

I am getting the following error on Linux using Blender 2.78a:

```
$: blender -b cube.blend -E CYCLES -x 1 -o cube -f 1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'OCLRT::xcb_error'
  what():  XCB ERROR: X session is not running!
Read new prefs: /home/mbomba/.config/blender/2.78/config/userpref.blend
read blend: /home/mbomba/Documents/art/3d/cube.blend
```

Update: 
To clarify, this works fine if executed in a terminal when an X session is running.  I'm wondering if it's a bug -- I was thinking about automating a cluster to render animations but the X dependency is kind of raining on my parade.

Update 2: 
I compiled a version of Blender using the WITH_HEADLESS flag and I get the same error when I run it without X.

Update 3: 
While I haven't been able to assimilate any of this information into a coherent solution, after some research I found that people encountered the same error occurs frequently with Beignet / Intel OpenCL driver installations.

Update 4: 
I tested this via ssh on another machine and it works fine.  It must be a problem specific my system.  I would like to know what library is causing this issue, but I plan to do most of my rendering on the other machine anyhow.

**SOLUTION**

As sambler suggested in the comment, changing `set(WITH_CYCLES_DEVICE_OPENCL TRUE)` to `set(WITH_CYCLES_DEVICE_OPENCL FALSE)` in `intern/cycles/CMakeLists.txt` prior to building allowed me to render with Cycles in a tty.  The issue must be related to the OpenCL drivers on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a while but I have rendered on a headless machine. I did have Xorg installed to be able to run x11 apps remotely but the was no running X-server on the remote machine.

If you want to get blender running without any X-server software installed then you will most likely have to [compile your own version of blender](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender). There is an option to build [`WITH_HEADLESS`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/CMakeLists.txt$265) that will disable all dependencies on Xorg libraries.

Comment: I think this is on the right track.  I attempted to compile Blender WITH_HEADLESS and the Python scripts were missing (crash and burn).  Going to attempt to compile with PYTHON_MODULE instead of PYTHON_INSTALL and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Those were just path config errors, it turns out.  The WITH_HEADLESS flag didn't work, on its own -- that disabled the GUI but Cycles crashes with the same XCB_ERROR in a tty.

Comment: I don't see it available to disable in ccmake but `intern/cycles/CMakeLists.txt` contains `set(WITH_CYCLES_DEVICE_OPENCL TRUE)`  you could try changing that to FALSE before building. Do you have `WITH_CYCLES_OPENSUBDIV` enabled? opensubdiv can use a gpu through cuda or glsl as well as opencl for acceleration.

Comment: Yes, a build without Cycles OpenCL did the trick -- good eye.

Answer (score 0):

See my example with one frame and *myfile.blend* - is a blend file with a video animation video and sound and one cube:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>blender.lnk --background c:\temp\myfile.blend
--render-output C:\tmp\ --render-frame 10 -E CYCLES -x 1 -o cube -f 1
Read new prefs: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.7
8\config\userpref.blend
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 48000hz, got 44100hz instead
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\python
read blend: c:\temp\myfile.blend
Fra:10 Mem:21.39M (0.00M, Peak 32.26M) | Time:00:00.00 | Sce:  Ve:0 Fa:0 La:0
Fra:10 Mem:21.39M (0.00M, Peak 32.26M) | Time:00:00.00 | Sce:  Ve:0 Fa:0 La:0
Append frame 10
 Time: 00:00.13 (Saving: 00:00.13)

Error: Could not open file for writing

Blender quit
```

Even this told me is on error I have output rendered.

I try with just one frame to test your issue.