# Render without a display adapter (XEN virtual machine)

Tags: rendering, gpu, command-line

I'm trying to have my server render out an animation, but it fails.
When I run blender -E help, I get "unable to open a display" (it's a headless server).

**Can Blender render without a GPU?**

Comment: [This question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/68698/935) may of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`--background` (`-b`)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html) flag to prevent blender from attempting to open a GUI.
`blender -b -E help` should work as expected.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your answer to add a link and re-organize the information a bit. If you disagree with my edits, [please don't hesitate to roll them back](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing).