# Can i run blender as on a server as a binary source code?

Tags: source-code

I want to be able to run blender on a server and use it to render images without having to install the GUI on the browser. Is such possible in blender ?

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68698/headless-blender-using-cycles-without-x-server and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34717/run-blender-without-gui

Answer (score 1):

You can use blender with no GUI, directly from a terminal or command line. As long as you can access the remote server (via ssh or remote desktop) you can issue commands to control blender.

The most basic command is

```
blender -b file.blend
```

-b will let Render in the background (without UI).

For a detailed list of other options read.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/workflows/command_line.html

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html